# Proguard not able to obfuscate all the classes

Tags: proguard

I have below class which is not obsfucate using proguard.

public class CallService : InCallService
public class MyConnectionService : ConnectionService

[Please find classes names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igr3G.png)